# SQL Query - Conditional Rolling Subtraction and Association

Tags: sql

Firstly I'll lay out my data in its simplified form to demonstrate what I'm dealing with:

Stock Table:

| Component | Quantity | Batch | Expiry Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brick | 1500 | B1 | 12/05/2023 |
| Brick | 1500 | B2 | 30/05/2023 |
| Brick | 1500 | B3 | 22/06/2023 |
| Steel | 2500 | S1 | 12/05/2023 |
| Steel | 2500 | S2 | 18/05/2023 |
| Glass | 15000 | G1 | 29/09/2023 |
| Glass | 15000 | G2 | 12/12/2023 |

Builds Table:

| Build ID | Req Component | Req Quantity | Req Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Steel | 5000 | 01/01/2023 |
| 1 | Brick | 4000 | 02/01/2023 |
| 1 | Glass | 10000 | 03/01/2023 |
| 2 | Steel | 5000 | 15/01/2023 |
| 2 | Brick | 4000 | 16/01/2023 |
| 2 | Glass | 10000 | 17/01/2023 |

What you see above is a table of stuck and the batches of said stock and their respective quantities. The next table is a list of upcoming builds and their material requirement.

Based on what I'm trying to achieve I would expect to see the following as the output.

| Build ID | Component | Req Quantity | Req Date | Assigned Batch | Rmn Qty(batch) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Steel | 5000 | 01/01/2023 | S1 | 2500 |
| 1 | Steel | 2500 | 01/01/2023 | S2 | 0 |
| 1 | Brick | 4000 | 02/01/2023 | B1 | 0 |
| 1 | Brick | 2500 | 02/01/2023 | B2 | 0 |
| 1 | Brick | 1000 | 02/01/2023 | B3 | 500 |
| 1 | Glass | 10000 | 03/01/2023 | G1 | 5000 |
| 2 | Steel | 5000 | 15/01/2023 | NO STOCK |  |
| 2 | Brick | 4000 | 16/01/2023 | B3 | 0 |
| 2 | Brick | 3500 | 16/01/2023 | NO STOCK |  |
| 2 | Glass | 10000 | 17/01/2023 | G1 | 0 |
| 2 | Glass | 5000 | 17/01/2023 | G2 | 10000 |

The stock is automatically assigned and distributed against the orders based on the required date and the expiry date - the rolling subtraction occurs that a batch may not be fully consumed on a given build and as such can be used again later.

If any more information is required please let me know.

Comment: You have no unique relation (column) to determine which rows on `Stock` table are related with which row on `Builds` table

Comment: Agree but ultimately the relation is dynamic other than the material required a single batch can satisfy multiple builds.